# Linq .include with select EF and retain object structure

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I have 3 classes Class A, Class B and Class C as structured below

```
public class A
{

  //other properties

  public List<B> Bs{get;set;}
  public List<C> Cs{get;set;}

}


public class B
{
  //other properties
  public List<C> Cs{get;set;}
}

public class C
{
  //properties
}
```

As you can see, class C is nested in both A and B.

The data in database is stored in
Cs Table As

```
 Id | AId  | BId
 ---------------
 1  | 10    | NULL
 2  | 20    | NULL
 3  | 40    | 100
```

I would like to exclude the IDs with Bid=NULL from class A but include in class B.

Here is what I have tried

```
 var A=db.A
       .include(i=>i.B.Select(j=>j.C))
       .include(i=>i.C)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am getting all data as expected except could not exclude data with Bid=Null from A.  Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If an anonymous result is OK, you can do:

```
var A= from a in db.A
       select new {
           A = a,
           B = a.B,
           C = a.C.Where(c => c.BId != null)
       }.ToList();
```

Otherwise something like this:

```
var A = db.A.Include(a => a.B).Single();
var children = db.C.Where(c => c.ParentID == parent.Id && c.BId != null);
foreach (var child in children) {
   A.C.Add(child);
}
```